# Как оставить SearchView открытым

Tags: android, android-search-view

У меня на ToolBar лупа - поиска. При клике SearchView раскрывается. Так вот мне нужно сделать так чтобы он всегда был открым... Как сделать?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Поиск"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    />
</menu>


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Поиск");

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась:

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(**true**);
```

а в XML:

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

Comment: в таком варианте у вас свернется поиск, ибо searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true); нужно заменить на false

Comment: нет наоборот так он всегда открытый!

Comment: Вы сперва проверьте потом минусуйте сколько пожелаете!!! Я тоже сперва думал что свернется поэтому true не делал! Но буржуйский SO помог!

Comment: Я обязательно проверю и отпишу. Но тогда ваш пример будет вопреки оф документации, в чем я сомневаюсь. Хотя бывает)

Comment: Копировал ваш код эмулировал 3 девайса. APi15 APi 21 API23 На всех, не работает. Получается, что вы где-то упускаете что-то раз ваш код для вас работает. Я просто рекомендую, ещё раз прочитать ответ, возможно вы не хотите понять как это работает. Ставлю false, всё работает как часы.

Comment: Я создал специально для этого новый проект(с чистого листа так сказать) и сделал именно так и заработал... Мистика какая-то...

Answer (score 3):

> If you want the search field to always be visible, then call setIconifiedByDefault(false).

"Если вы хотите, чтоб поле поиска было всегда видимым, тогда вызовите(используйте) setIconifiedByDefault(false)"

в xml

```
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```

программно:

```
searchView.setIconified(false);
```

Что касается именно вашего вопроса: в xml убедитесь, чтоб стояло `showAsAction="always"` а после программно, измените так:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

Comment: Это уже использовал, тут иконка лупа съезжает из своего места, то есть на право!

Comment: покажите код тогда

Comment: Значит ошибка в другом, покажите код разметки serchview и менюItem. Там есть пару моментов которые надо правильно поставить.

Comment: Так проблема не в том что поле не видно, а то что виджет так реагирует?  Так вы напишите, что проблема решилась, но значок уехал куда-то, это совершенно другой вопрос. Мб для того, чтоб вам сделать более гибкий toolbar просто нарисовать красивый edittext и поставить imaveview какой хотите вместо иконки? по мне так быстрей и удобней будет, ну решать вам.